# how to copy from excel to outlook and keep the format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

Sometimes I copy a part of an microsoft excel file to microsoft outlook, the format is ok, but sometimes it's wrong -- there are extra white spaces before the content of each cell so that it looks like for each row in excel, after pasting to outlook there's an extra row.

What can I do to make the copy & paste work?

Comment: Can you post some examples? Without that it's difficult to understand your issue. Have you looked for non-printing characters?

Comment: no there's no non-printing characters... how to upload an example excel?

Comment: At first please upload screenshot of a table already pasted to outlook, make sure non-printing characters are also visible.

Comment: I often find the column widths pasted into Word from Excel aren't wide enough. I usually get around this by auto-sizing the columns in Excel and then I reduce the font size by 1 or 2 points before copy/pasting across to Word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean pasting Excel data into email body.

1) In order to not mess formats I select part of the sheet I want to copy, classic Ctrl+C and use special paste in Outlook 2010, ie. right click and choose paste as 'picture'. Usually works ok, but if not:

2) Alternatively you can try another copy mode (Excel 2010+). Select range in Excel then find on the ribbon the 'Copy' icon, click on small triangle on the right and choose 'Copy as Picture'. Then you can select several options regarding details: as on screen or as printed, and picture or bitmap. The picture format can be easily scaled after pasting it to Word or Outlook, while keeping original formatting. Try experimenting.

Answer (score 6):

just to share my methode.

I will copy from excel and paste into Word.

then only I copy the whole thing again and paste it into my Outlook.

hope this help.

Comment: this is a nice trick, Excel to Word to Outlook, Totally Microsoft Style. I wish they could learn something from Apple. But, it takes years. oh, wait, it's 2018 already...

Comment: Still doesn't work properly without extra effort in 2022...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the problem could also be described as there are non-visible characters in each cell prior to the actual numerical data and that results in the cell being 2 rows high instead of just one. Placing your cursor to the left of the actual numerical data and pressing 'backspace' about 4 times deletes those unwanted characters. By doing that for each cell in a row, the row will be reduced back to just one line as would normally be expected (i.e. teh preceding blank line is eliminated). the method I just described is the way in which I used to resolve this problem, but when there are many numerical cells in the table, this becomes quite tedious.

I have found a quicker method is to simply select all the numerical cells in the table that was pasted into the email message and click on the text center button (or type Ctrl-E) followed by the text right button (or type Ctrl-R). this appears to eliminate all the non-visible characters reducing the row height and properly left-align the numbers.
The above was assumes a PC and Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

Copying as a picture is NOT a solution, folks! 
You want the table to be editable when sending to someone.

I don't know why this works, but it does:

1. Hide the first column in the spreadsheet. If you have to, add a column before A column and then hide it.
2. Filter data if needed that you want to email
3. Highlight all cells.  I do this from bottom right to top left.
4. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
5. Right click Outlook / New Email Icon (running at bottom)
6. Type in name of person to email in the TO box
7. Move to body of message and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice (don't type anything). 
   Paste table (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

I pass through OneNote to generate a preformat mail which embeds an Excel. Unfortunately it is automatically converted to a picture

Answer (score 1):

Community found the solution it may help many of you, just copy and paste desire excel in your Gmail in composing window and then copy it from here and paste it into outlook email composing window that surely will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that may help.

I had the same problem: when I copy & paste Excel tables into Outlook emails it sometimes keeps formats but sometimes (on a random basis?) the table is pasted as plain text. Paste Special option in disabled in such cases.

I realized pasting the Excel table in a brand new e-mail works fine (i.e. keeps formats). The issue only appears when replying an e-mail.

Hope this helps.

Office 365, Excel 2016, Outlook 2016. Email server: Google (G Suite).

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with same issue and found an easy fix.

Just add one row in the area you copy and make sure all columns are not merged. Then select the area (left to right) you want to copy and add a bottom border (Home - Font)

If you don't like to see the border, use a white bottom border.

Now just copy (CTRL C) paste (CTRL V) from Excel into a new mail message and the column width stays like the Excel

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when pasting numbers formatted as "Custom" into Outlook. Changing the format to "Number" and then copy/pasting resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where in excel there was a custom number formatting which wasn't apparent at first view.
*-* #,##0*-;-* #,##0_-;*-* "-"??*-;*-@*-

and when this was pasted into Outlook it couldn't cope with that format and resized the column width so that the a cell went over two rows rather than one.

So I changed the number format to a simple #,000; -#,000; -

And now my table copies properly.

Answer (score 0):

First select the required data and and use the **Format as table** function from the **Home** tab.

Then copy your data and paste directly in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

This will only help in some instances but I found that if you copy "visible" area from excel and paste into Outlook it keeps the formatting. If your spreadsheet is larger than what can be seen on the screen (set to 100% viewing, can't cheat it by shrinking, I tried), it won't work. Luckily for mine I was able to hide some columns that weren't needed to fit viewable space and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I usually copy the table from excel and paste into outlook client and then copy from the client and paste into the web outlook. It works.

Yes, for this you need outlook client on your local machine.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that suggests that web Outlook is being used.